# C++ Illegal Indirection with Nodes

Tags: c++, sorting, queue, nodes, bubble-sort

I've been trying to get a way to sort my Nodes (doubly linked) based on their "Priority" value/variable. However I keep getting stuck at an "Illegal Indirection" error, and not sure what it means (despite looking around).

Any help would be greatly appreciated, here is the code, it was taken from another answered question similar to mine on stackOverflow, so it may be implemented wrongly, but I've supplied part of my Node Class, and the function that uses the Sorting function (within a 'Queue Class');

I've highlighted the error (well pointed it out) in the "Sorting Function" block, any help is appreciated.

***NODE CLASS***

```
class Node
{
public:
Node *next;         //Pointer to the next node
Node *prev;         //Pointer to the previous node
Node(N i, int s, Node *nextptr, Node *prevptr = NULL, int currentPriority = 0, int currentId = 0)   //Defines the components that make up the Node Class/Objects
{
    val = i;                        //Value/Data input by the user upon creation of the Node.
    priority = currentPriority;     //Priority setting of the Node set by the user
    processId = currentId;          //Unique ID of the Node differentiating it from all other nodes
    size = s;                       //Total number of Nodes.
    next = nextptr;                 //Pointer to the Next Node (Down the Queue)
    prev = prevptr;                 //Pointer to the previous Node (Up the Queue)
}


private:

N val;              //Template variable of a value input by the user
int size;           //Size variable of the total number of nodes
int priority;       //Variable input by the user to determine where in the queue the node is placed
int processId;      //Variable automatically set when the node is created. Unique to each Node.
};
```

***Function that Calls it***

```
void Queue::Display(void)
{   

    bubbleSort(front);

        cout << '\n';
    }
```

***SORTING FUNCTION***

```
    void bubbleSort(Node<T> *&start)
{
    int size = back->getProcessId();
    int i = 0;

    Node<T> *lastSwapped = NULL;

    while (size--)
    {
        Node<T>
            *current = start,
            *prev = NULL,
            *currentSwapped = NULL;

        while (current->getPrev() != NULL)
        {
            Node<T> *after = current->getPrev();


ERROR IS HERE >>> if (*current->getPriority() > *after->getPriority())


            {
                current->next = after->next;
                after->next = current;
                if (prev == NULL)                   
                    start = after;
                else
                    prev->next = after;

                prev = after;
                currentSwapped = current;
            }           
            else
            {
                prev = current;
                current = current->getPrev();
            }
        }

        if (currentSwapped == NULL)
            break;
        else
            lastSwapped = currentSwapped;
    }
}
```

Comment: You already called `current->getPrev()` correctly. Just do the same for `current->getPriority()`. No need for the extra `*`s.

Comment: Ah thanks, yeah I fixed it an hour later after posting, by removing the * s, but I wasn't sure why it was wrong, so thanks for the explanation :)